# CSR certificate request for push notifications

Tags: xcode, apple-push-notifications, csr

Do CSR certificates need to be generated for every individual app ID you want to enable push notifications in? Or can you use the same one in each app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my knowledge, Yes. Each certificate is tied to a appID and if the appID is changed its need to be a new certificate and using that certificate you have to generate a CSR.